# In 7 wonders when you buy resources from neighbor do you take the card?

Tags: 7-wonders

When you buy resources from neighbor do you take the card or just get access to the resources you need?

Comment: That would make some kind of really interesting variant, but it's definitely not the basic rule :)

Answer (score 8):

No, you do not take the card. The neighbor retains the card; you are simply allowed to use your neighbor's cards, for a fee of course.

You can also buy the resource from the top corner of the civilization cards as well.  It doesn't need to be a "card".

Comment: I agree. Cards are not resources, it's more like a shop. You don't take the shop when you buy things in it.

Comment: But it does need to be gray or brown, stuff from yellow cards cannot be purchased.

Answer (score 2):

**Just the resources.**

The [rules](http://www.rprod.com/files/7W_RULES_EN_COLOR_LIGHT.pdf) on page 4 define things pretty well.

Cards are called "structures", the brown ones can generate "resources"

> Often, a player will want to build a structure requiring resources he or she does not produce.
>
> If these resources are produced by a neighboring city – players sitting directly to the left or right of that player – the player will be able to purchase the missing resource(s) through commerce.

In red, there is a notice:

> Important : the resources are not spent during construction. They can be used each turn, for the entire game. The production of a city is never reduced (the cards played are never discarded).

Obviously if you were to take the card, the production of the city would be reduced and this is prohibited.